# Display only author posts in author page in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, author

What should I do to display only a certain author posts, in my author.php page? I don't mean an specific author (using author ID), but the default page for authors. With the current code, its displaying posts from all the other authors. Should I use a specific query?

```
<?php   $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $custom_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    // 'order' => 'DESC',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'paged' => $paged
    );

// custom query
$recent_posts = new WP_Query($custom_args);

// check that we have results
if($recent_posts->have_posts()) : ?>

<ul class="article_list">

    <?php
    // start loop
    while ($recent_posts->have_posts() ) : $recent_posts->the_post(); ?>

    <li class="regular">
        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
            <div class="text">
                <p class="category"><?php foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) { echo $category->cat_name . ' '; } ?></p>
                <p class="autor"><?php the_author(); ?></p>
                <h3 class="article_title"><?php echo mb_strimwidth(get_the_title(), 0, 80, '...'); ?></h3>
                <p class="date"><?php echo get_the_date( 'Y-m-d' ); ?></p>
            </div>
            <div class="mask">
              <?php
              $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );
              echo '<div class="art_img" style="background: url('. $url.')"></div>';
              ?>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
<?php endif;
echo '<div class="pagination">';
if(function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) { wp_pagenavi(array( 'query' => $recent_posts )); }
echo '</div>';
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use get_posts function of wordpress.

Here is reference:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

Pass the required authors Id in the argument list.

Answer (score 0):

Hello just add `global $current_user;` above `$paged` variable on top of your provided snippet and add `'author' =>  $current_user->ID,` in your array of `$custom_args` so it will display posts of specific user in author page

Comment: Its only working for the current logged user, but not for other authors.

Answer (score 0):

Add author__in into your query

Try this

```
<?php $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $custom_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'author__in'=> array(2,4,6), //Authors's id's you like to include
    // 'order' => 'DESC',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'paged' => $paged
);
```

Comment: Do I always have to use the authors ID? Is there a way to use a query to call the post of whoever the author I clicked on?